# Android BLE scanning not parsing ScanRecord on some devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetoothlescanner

My problem is the that on some devices the `ScanResult.getDevice()` or `ScanResult.getScanRecord()` both return null on some Android devices but works fine on most.  If I can't call `getDevice()` reliably how can I connect?

When I look at the toString of results in my onScanResult of the callback I do see a small difference between devices that work and do not.

This is the result string with a failing device.

```
{device=F1:6B:2E:01:43:88, scanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=5, mServiceUuids=null, mServiceSolicitationUuids=[], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=MYDEVICE], rssi=-38, timestampNanos=10844927511936, eventType=27, primaryPhy=1, secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=255, txPower=127, periodicAdvertisingInterval=0}
```

This is the result string with a working device.

```
{device=F1:6B:2E:01:43:88, scanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=5, mServiceUuids=null, mServiceSolicitationUuids=[], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=MYDEVICE, **mTDSData=null**], rssi=-65, timestampNanos=131383632077590, eventType=27, primaryPhy=1, secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=255, txPower=127, periodicAdvertisingInterval=0}
```

The one difference I noticed was that the failing device does not include **mTDSData=null**

Details of my setup:

- nrf51422 BLE peripheral.
- Compiling Android api 30 min api 23
- Working device Moto G7 running Android 10 with Bluetooth 4.2
- Failing device RCA 7" running Android 10 with Bluetooth 4.0